# How do I send req.query correctly?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

My problem is how can I bring my data structure into the query? I want to be able to search everything via one interface. How can I implement this?

This is my data structure:

```
"basicData": {
  "tasks":[
     {"title": "Flottenmanagement"},
     {"title": "OCPP Backend"}
    ]
}
```

My Code:

```
export const allCompanyData = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (req.query) {
    Company.find(req.query).then(docs => {
      logger.info(`Query works ${req.query}`);
      res.json({
        query: req.query
      })
      res.status(200).json(docs);
    }).catch(err => {
      logger.error(`Error ${err}`);
      res.status(400).json(`Error ${err}`)
    })
  } else {
    Company.find()
      .then((items: any) => {
        logger.info("Successful finding");
        res.status(200).json(items);
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        logger.error(`Error ${err}`);
        res.status(400).json(`Error ${err}`);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share some more information on what is not working? Do you get an error? What have you tried to make it work so far?

Comment: I tried to enter the query without the link. Namely ?basicData.tasks.title=Fleetmanagement and now I want to search for another title. And I don't know how to implement this?

Comment: Fleetmanagement = Flottenmanagement in the code